# Why is my program not printing correctly?

Tags: python, definition

The explanation is below:

```
def displaySortedNumbers(num1, num2, num3):
    smallest = num1
    if num2 < smallest:
        smallest = num2
    if num3 < smallest:
        smallest = num3

    return smallest

def main():
    num1, num2, num3 = eval(input("Enter three numbers seperated by commas:"))
    print("The numbers are,",displaySortedNumbers(num1, num2, num3))

main()
```

After the three numbers are entered, the smallest number prints out but the rest of the numbers do not follow. I need the numbers to print out from smallest to largest. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: well you are returning only smallest `return smallest`. Your function `displaySortedNumbers` only finds the smallest. It isn't sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your return statement there is only ´smallest´, not the other variables.

You can store the values in a list, sort it and then return that list, just like this

```
def displaySortedNumbers(num1, num2, num3):
    list = [num1, num2, num3]
    list.sort()
    return list
```

Comment: I'm not sure what else to return, I tried to return displaySortedNumbers(num1, num2, num3).

Comment: You can make a list and then sort it like this ´list = [num1, num2, num3]´ then ´list.sort()´ and finally ´return list´

Comment: If you can use built-in functions, just return sorted((num1, num2, num3)) would suffice

Answer (score 2):

Your function is only returning the one smallest number of the provided three, you may consider using a list and sorting it instead if that works for you.

```py
def displaySortedNumbers(num1, num2, num3):
    s = ""
    for c in sorted([num1, num2, num3]):
        s += " " + str(c)
    return s
```

The `sorted()` function takes an iterable argument and returns it sorted by a key, however in this case, if you are just sorting it in increasing order, you do not need to input a key.

Answer (score 0):

In your return statement, you only return one of the three numbers, the one you deem the smallest. But your function is expected to return all three numbers sorted. I'm guessing you can't use the built-in `sorted()` function and so you need to program the sort manually. You can do a simple bubble sort on 3 numbers by changing your function to be the following:

```
def displaySortedNumbers(num1, num2, num3):
    if num2 < num1:
        num1, num2 = num2, num1
    if num3 < num2:
        num2, num3 = num3, num2
    if num2 < num1:
        num1, num2 = num2, num1
    return num1, num2, num3
```

This will print all three numbers, properly sorted.

If you CAN use built-in functions, you could simply say:

```
def displaySortedNumbers(num1, num2, num3):
    return sorted((num1, num2, num3))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to rewrite like this:

```
if smallest > num2:
    smallest = num2
elif smallest > num3:
    smallest = num3
```

Comment: I tried that and it printed the same thing.